# Binomial summation including de moivre's theorem

Tags: complex-numbers, binomial-theorem

[Here i m also attaching the link to the solution if someone can refer through it and explain it to me it would be so helpful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsznM.jpg) The question is simply asking $\sum_{r=0}^5 C_{6r}^{32}$.
As I saw a jump of 6 in the binomial coefficients, I started thinking with the direction of de moivre's theorem and considered the expansion of $({1+x})^{32}$ and i m substituting the value of x by relating the de moivre's theorem using cos (something) + i sin (something) but i cannot get the correct approach and solve it

Comment: With just 6 terms in the sum, is it so wrong to just brute force the sum? Or are you asked to use something like de moivre explicitly?

Comment: @AlkaKadri Yes it is mentioned to be solved using de moivre's theorem

Comment: @AlkaKadri i think i should drop the image of the solution it would be helpful to refer that

Comment: The solution is right there in the book as it turns out! Is there are particular part of it that is troubling you?

Comment: @AlkaKadri Yaa like while substituting x=cos(2 pi r / 6) + ... i can't get that part that why we substituted that and then how it resolves our problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just diving into the solution a bit, the first thing to recall is the binomial theorem:
$$\begin{align} 
(x + y)^n &= \sum_{r=0}^n C_r^n x^{n-r} y^r \\
\Rightarrow (1 + x)^n &= \sum_{r=0}^n C_r^n x^{r}
\end{align}$$
Recognizing that there is a "jump of 6" in evaluating $\sum_{r=0}^{5} C_{6r}^{32}$, the key is to then use the sixth roots of unity as given in the book:
$$ x = \cos\frac{2\pi r}{6} + i \sin\frac{2\pi r}{6} = e^{2\pi i r/6} \quad ; \quad r = 0,1,\dots,5$$
Where de Moivre's theorem comes in is if we let $\xi = \cos\frac{2\pi}{6} + i \sin\frac{2\pi}{6} = e^{2\pi i/6}$, then the above values of $x$ are just $1, \xi, \xi^2, \dots \xi^5$. Then consider,
$$\begin{align} 
(1 + 1)^{32} &= \sum_{r=0}^n C_r^n \\
(1 + \xi)^{32} &= \sum_{r=0}^n C_r^n \xi^{r}\\
(1 + \xi^2)^{32} &= \sum_{r=0}^n C_r^n \xi^{2r}\\
&\vdots\\
(1 + \xi^5)^{32} &= \sum_{r=0}^n C_r^n \xi^{5r}
\end{align}$$
Adding these sums together gives,
$$\begin{align} 
(1 + 1)^{32} + (1 + \xi)^{32} + \dots + (1 + \xi^5)^{32} &= \sum_{r=0}^n C_r^n \left(1 + \xi^{r} + \xi^{2r} + \dots + \xi^{5r} \right)
\end{align}$$
Now notice that if $r$ is a multiple of $6$, then $\xi^r = 1$ so that $\left(1 + \xi^{r} + \xi^{2r} + \dots + \xi^{5r} \right) = 6$. Otherwise, we can use the geometric formula
$$ 1 + \xi^{r} + \xi^{2r} + \dots + \xi^{5r} = \frac{1 - \xi^{r(5+1)}}{1 - \xi^r} = \frac{1 - 1}{1 - \xi^r} = 0$$
Thus, only every sixth term of the sum survives so that
$$ (1 + 1)^{32} + (1 + \xi)^{32} + \dots + (1 + \xi^5)^{32} = 6 \sum_{r=0}^n C_{6r}^n $$
The solution in the book carries on from here.

Comment: Thanks a lot there it was very helpful

Answer (score 3):

let :$$w = \cos \left({\frac{\pi}{3}}\right)+i\sin\left({\frac{\pi}{3}}\right) \\ f(x)=(1+x)^n$$

We have :
$$1+w^k+w^{2k}+w^{3k}+w^{4k}+w^{5k}=\begin{cases} 6|k : 6 \\ \text{otherwise :0}\end{cases}$$

we have :$$(1+x)^n=\sum^n_{k=0}\binom{n}{k}x^k$$
Therfore:
$$f(1)+f(w)+f(w^2)+f(w^3)+f(w^4)+f(w^5)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left({1+w^k+w^{2k}+w^{3k}+w^{4k}+w^{5k}}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{6} \rfloor} 6\binom{n}{6k}$$

finally:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{6} \rfloor} \binom{n}{6k}=\frac{f(1)+f(w)+f(w^2)+f(w^3)+f(w^4)+f(w^5)}{6}$$

Therfore:
$$f(x)=(1+x)^{32}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{32}{6} \rfloor} \binom{32}{6k}=\sum_{k=0}^{5} \binom{n}{6k}=\frac{f(1)+f(w)+f(w^2)+f(w^3)+f(w^4)+f(w^5)}{6}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot there it was helpful

Comment: You'r Welcom   General put $$ w = \cos \left({\frac{2\pi}{p}}\right)+i\sin\left({\frac{2\pi}{p}}\right)$$ $$f(x)=(1+x)^n$$ $$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{p} \rfloor} \binom{n}{pk} = \frac{\sum^{n-1}_{k=0} f(w^k)}{p}$$